# Javascript Readable Stream to Java InputStream (React Server Side Rendering to Stream in Spring Boot)

Tags: graalvm

Is there a way to convert Javascripts Readable stream (I think this is a node type): https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) into Java's inputStream using GraalVM for java8.

A little background:

I have a React Web App with a Spring Boot backend. I am using Reacts.renderToString method to render my application on Server Side using GraalVMs Javascript engine and serve it to the client.

I wanted to improve my apps performance by utilizing Reacts.renderToNodeStream method stream the rendered page to the client.

And this would somehow require me to pipe the Stream created in the javascript engine through Java, to the client... Wonder if this is possible.